# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 1, length 0

Tags: java, parsing, indexoutofboundsexception, txt

I'm trying to parse information that will come from a text field. Previously, I had it in a separate txt file, and it was in two lines, but if I use the code below due to data (which was previously defined as `String`) it gives this error (see after the code...)

```
int[] parsedData = new int[36];
int[] navigation=new int [9];
data = textField.getText()+" END"+textField_1.getText() + " END";
for(int i = 0; i < 36; i++){
   parsedData[i] = Integer.parseInt(data.substring(0,2));
   data = data.substring(3);
}
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    navigation[i] = Integer.parseInt(traverse.substring(0,1));
    traverse = traverse.substring(2);
}
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 1, length 0
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3720)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1909)
    at Solver$2.actionPerformed(Solver.java:82)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: The trace tells you where the problem is. It is on line 82 (in your ActionListener). So figure out which variable is incorrect and why and then fix the problem. You probably have a logic error in your looping code. Add debug code to display the text that you are parsing in each iteration of your loop.

Comment: Where is this `traverse` variable getting its string data so that this `traverse.substring(0,1)` would even fly. It obviously contains nothing.